# Heat Map using Chart::Gnuplot Perl

Tags: perl, gnuplot, heatmap

I was trying to create something like [image]

But I was not able to get the x and y axis tics coming in 
I tried something like this to see if the x axis tics are coming

```
my @data = (
        [0, 0, 10],
        [0, 1, 10],
        [0, 2, 10],
        [],
        [1, 0, 10],
        [1, 1, 5],
        [1, 2, 10],
        [],
        [2, 0, 10],
        [2, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 10],
        [],
        [3, 0, 10],
        [3, 1, 0],
        [3, 2, 10],
       );

my $chart = Chart::Gnuplot->new(
    output => "test1.png",
    title  => "3D plot from arrays of x, y and z coordinates",
    xlabel => 'x',
    ylabel => 'y',
    xtics  => {
        labels => ['"pi" 3.1416', '"-pi" -3.1416'],
    },

);
$chart->set(pm3d => 'map');
$chart->set(palette => 'defined (0 0 0 1, 1 1 1 0, 2 1 0 0)');
my $dataSet = Chart::Gnuplot::DataSet->new(

    points => \@data,
);

$chart->plot3d($dataSet);
```

I am not sure how the dataset should be and how the x and y axis tics should be added
I tested the above with some examples that I got from the internet but was not able to see the result . 
Any help to get this like the image would be greatly appreciated

Got one more issue, when tried to get all the values on X and Y axis, the xtics and ytics are not showing fully as in the above image, the one I got seems like this
[image]

The dataset is like this

```
[
            0,
            1,
            '2.66556908091426'
          ],
          [
            0,
            2,
            '4.37897014657203'
          ],
          [
            0,
            3,
            '1.22514023397498'
          ],
          [
            0,
            4,
            '4.53000730040497'
          ],
          [
            0,
            5,
            '3.01982096624856'
          ],
          [
            0,
            6,
            '0.499618756879272'
          ],
          [
            0,
            7,
            '4.84182728928223'
          ],
          [
            0,
            8,
            '1.96005062661005'
          ],
          [
            0,
            9,
            '2.42800730644825'
          ],
          [
            0,
            10,
            '1.86670807696721'
          ],
          [
            0,
            11,
            '1.81614100038358'
          ],
          [
            0,
            12,
            '4.39616981937487'
          ],
          [
            0,
            13,
            '3.35256272447085'
          ],
          [
            0,
            14,
            '3.24814393010016'
          ],
          [
            0,
            15,
            '1.06219230833835'
          ],
          [
            0,
            16,
            '1.12793288928973'
          ],
          [
            0,
            17,
            '3.26476861756371'
          ],
          [
            0,
            18,
            '3.10578946862982'
          ],
          [
            0,
            19,
            '2.93146341009402'
          ],
          [
            0,
            20,
            '1.72192716962012'
          ],
          [
            0,
            21,
            '4.04316953579938'
          ],
          [
            0,
            22,
            '0.32291976646917'
          ],
          [
            0,
            23,
            '4.42019093014144'
          ],
          [
            0,
            24,
            '3.31129513399691'
          ],
          [
            0,
            25,
            '4.561835018284'
          ],
          [
            0,
            26,
            '1.23709783845847'
          ],
          [
            0,
            27,
            '2.65864379090912'
          ],
          [
            0,
            28,
            '2.30212288203429'
          ],
          [
            0,
            29,
            '0.621743568938786'
          ],
          [
            0,
            30,
            '1.80416068716383'
          ],
          [
            0,
            31,
            '2.66465304546164'
          ],
          [
            0,
            32,
            '3.45680173240485'
          ],
          [
            0,
            33,
            '2.70739617274879'
          ],
          [
            0,
            34,
            '1.11428672300967'
          ],
          [
            0,
            35,
            '1.67761705545201'
          ],
          [
            0,
            36,
            '2.74299975084073'
          ],
          [
            0,
            37,
            '1.80397491377351'
          ],
          [
            0,
            38,
            '4.47728976228916'
          ],
          [
            0,
            39,
            '4.68895286431879'
          ],
          [
            0,
            40,
            '0.14021332300036'
          ],
          [
            0,
            41,
            '2.33736192052044'
          ],
          [
            0,
            42,
            '0.177482592020581'
          ],
          [
            0,
            43,
            '4.73906999291613'
          ],
          [
            0,
            44,
            '2.31796437164231'
          ],
          [
            0,
            45,
            '3.99016409499582'
          ],
          [
            0,
            46,
            '3.38293261332254'
          ],
          [
            0,
            47,
            '2.61350773461833'
          ],
          [
            0,
            48,
            '4.73763682658106'
          ],
          [
            0,
            49,
            '0.882213941365624'
          ],
          [
            0,
            50,
            '0.772076148467349'
          ],
          [
            0,
            51,
            '0.211627911950369'
          ],
          [
            0,
            52,
            '0.983901796963771'
          ],
          [
            0,
            53,
            '4.20512536118553'
          ],
          [
            0,
            54,
            '1.23297443353948'
          ],
          [
            0,
            55,
            '3.81554353946163'
          ],
          [
            0,
            56,
            '3.65498488100304'
          ],
          [
            0,
            57,
            '2.57928958709011'
          ],
          [
            0,
            58,
            '2.59561593117475'
          ],
          [
            0,
            59,
            '0.00576648038274286'
          ],
          [
            0,
            60,
            '3.7901264909274'
          ],
          [
            0,
            61,
            '2.01073954816936'
          ],
          [
            0,
            62,
            '4.20235419868604'
          ],
          [
            0,
            63,
            '0.0699755500835941'
          ],
          [
            0,
            64,
            '1.89704728306967'
          ],
          [
            0,
            65,
            '3.60775496050488'
          ],
          [
            0,
            66,
            '0.210700948492715'
          ],
          [
            0,
            67,
            '1.46456716998541'
          ],
          [
            0,
            68,
            '1.17475107720264'
          ],
          [
            0,
            69,
            '3.05671437798837'
          ],
          [
            0,
            70,
            '2.68927795266336'
          ],
          [
            0,
            71,
            '2.51310517387102'
          ],
          [
            0,
            72,
            '2.47339733795219'
          ],
          [
            0,
            73,
            '0.0279383841017911'
          ],
          [
            0,
            74,
            '0.722901884055389'
          ],
          [
            0,
            75,
            '2.87491127698443'
          ],
          [
            0,
            76,
            '4.06219968687022'
          ],
          [
            0,
            77,
            '1.10014911730135'
          ],
          [
            0,
            78,
            '2.12579086549013'
          ],
          [
            0,
            79,
            '0.969934599414497'
          ],
          [
            0,
            80,
            '0.0104263290325335'
          ],
          [
            0,
            81,
            '4.76235946351673'
          ],
          [
            0,
            82,
            '0.790123228138313'
          ],
          [
            0,
            83,
            '0.0974340515172223'
          ],
          [
            0,
            84,
            '2.25078802534153'
          ],
          [
            0,
            85,
            '1.52078958155231'
          ],
          [
            0,
            86,
            '1.81615557330844'
          ],
          [
            0,
            87,
            '4.29625290304719'
          ],
          [
            0,
            88,
            '3.46711963355933'
          ],
          [
            0,
            89,
            '3.9427030133586'
          ],
          [
            0,
            90,
            '0.10345150062939'
          ],
          [
            0,
            91,
            '3.43953703174092'
          ],
          [
            0,
            92,
            '4.31073758997368'
          ],
          [
            0,
            93,
            '2.58639853373042'
          ],
          [
            0,
            94,
            '4.08224212269872'
          ],
          [],
```

Comment: Your data set looks fine, what was your question about it? Regarding the `xticks`: I tested this with `xtics => {labels => [0, 1, 2, 3]}` and the labels shows fine. The `x` labels you used (3.14 and -3.14) are outside the data range, so they will not show.

Comment: I need to see the x and y axis values like in the image above(01-oct, 02-oct ), Should I add it in the dataset or do i add it in xtics or ytics?

Comment: See my answer for an example of how you can set the ticks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example of how you can set the axis labels:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use Chart::Gnuplot;

my @data = (
        [0, 0, 10],
        [0, 1, 10],
        [0, 2, 10],
        [0, 3, 10],
        [],
        [1, 0, 10],
        [1, 1, 5],
        [1, 2, 10],
        [1, 3, 10],
        [],
        [2, 0, 10],
        [2, 1, 1],
        [2, 2, 1],
        [2, 3, 10],
        [],
        [3, 0, 10],
        [3, 1, 0],
        [3, 2, 5],
        [3, 3, 10],
       );

my $chart = Chart::Gnuplot->new(
    bg         => 'white',
    pm3d       => 'map',
    palette    => 'defined (0 0 0 1, 1 1 1 0, 2 1 0 0)',
    output     => "test.png",
    title      => "3D plot from arrays of x, y and z coordinates",
    xlabel     => 'x',
    ylabel     => 'y',
    xtics      => {
        labels   => ['"0030" 0', '"0100" 1', '"0130" 2', '"0200" 3'],
        rotate   => 90,
    },
    ytics      => {
        labels   => ['"04-Oct" 0', '"03-Oct" 1', '"02-Oct" 2', '"01-Oct" 3'],
    },
);
my $dataSet = Chart::Gnuplot::DataSet->new( points => \@data );
$chart->plot3d($dataSet);
```

[image]

**Update**:

You can create the `xtics` in a loop like this (given a DataTime `$dt`):

```
my @xtics;
for ( my $i=0; $i<($interval_count-1); $i++ ){
    $dt->add(minutes => $interval_period);
    my $xtic = '"' . $dt->hour . ':' . $dt->minute . '"' . ' ' . $i;
    push @xtics, $xtic;
}
```

Then set the `xtics` parameter to `Chart::Gnuplot->new()` like this:

```
xtics => { labels => \@xtics, rotate => 90, },
```

Comment: I have a doubt, Can I use xtic label inside loop like this:
my $xtics;
for(my $i=0;$i<($interval_count-1);$i++){
  $dt->add(minutes => $interval_period); 
  $xtics .= "'".'"'.$dt->hour.':'.$dt->minute.'"'.' '.$i."',";
 }
 $xtics =~ s/,$//;
and inside gnuplot->new(), give xtic the value
xtics      => {
      labels => [$xtic],
          rotate   => 90,
     },
but its showing me error- Invalid expression

Comment: I got an issue with Xtics and Ytics not showing fully, may be its the space?I added the code imagesize => "0.8, 0.5" but doesn't seem anything good. Added the details in the question

Comment: @Jitesh Could you send me the whole code you are working with? Then I will have a look at it. (My email is in my profile)

Comment: mailed you the details