# Can I plot matrix data in Chart::Gnuplot(Perl)?

Tags: perl, gnuplot

I need to do gnulot script of "splot '$map' matrix with image" in my perl codes, which means I need like heat map generated from data containing Z values only. I use Chart::Gnuplot but I have no idea how to do that with it. The below codes may not work correctly, I just put my code here just for reference.

```
@map = ([1.01E-6, 0.91E-6, 0.85E-6, ...], [1.13E-6, 1.32E-6, 1.85E-6, ...] .... );

my $chart = Chart::Gnuplot->new(
        terminal => "jpeg",
        bg         => 'white',
        pm3d       => 'map',
        palette    => 'defined (0 "green", 2.5E-6 "yellow", 5.0E-6  "red")',
        output     => $fileName,
        title      => $pName,
        xlabel     => 'x',
        ylabel     => 'y',
    );

$chart->set(xrange => $xmin, $xmax);
$chart->set(yrange => $ymin, $ymax);
$chart->set(view => 'map');

my $dataSet = Chart::Gnuplot::DataSet->new(matrix => \@map); # I just tried to check if this works.
# Plot the graph
$chart->plot3d($dataSet);
```

Comment: Reference to an aswer [Heat Map using Chart::Gnuplot Perl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55272831/heat-map-using-chartgnuplot-perl)

Comment: I am not sure but I think "Heat Map using Chart::Gnuplot Perl " is not for the matrix data. @map is only contains z data.

Comment: Have you tried to create plot with gnuplot with specifying gnuplot 'specification' file how the data should be drawn? You should post this file (set of gnuplot commands) and sample of data file. Otherwise it is not clear what the problem is. Have you checked gnuplot demo which best fit for your case?

Comment: I can't handle gnuplot right now. I'd like to get the map like the first one of http://gnuplot.sourceforge.net/demo/heatmaps.html with Chart::Gnuplot.

Answer (score 1):

When I use using => '1:2:3 with image' in the Chart::Gnuplot::DataSet->new, gnuplot drew what I wanted.

```
my @data = (
         [0, 0, 3.06E-6],
         [0, 1, 3.13E-6],
         [0, 2, 2.99E-6],
         [0, 3, 2.98E-6],
         [0, 4, 3.12E-6],
         [],
         [1, 0, 3.11E-6],
         [1, 1, 3.21E-6],
         [1, 2, 3.00E-6],
         [1, 3, 3.12E-6],
         [1, 4, 3.23E-6],
         [],
         [2, 0, 3.32E-6],
         [2, 1, 2.97E-6],
         [2, 2, 3.00E-6],
         [2, 3, 3.30E-6],
         [2, 4, 3.12E-6],
         [],
         [3, 0, 3.05E-6],
         [3, 1, 3.33E-6],
         [3, 2, 3.32E-6],
         [3, 3, 3.19E-6],
         [3, 4, 3.20E-6],
         [],
         [4, 0, 3.21E-6],
         [4, 1, 3.23E-6],
         [4, 2, 3.22E-6],
         [4, 3, 3.00E-6],
         [4, 4, 3.11E-6],
     );
    my $chart = Chart::Gnuplot->new(
        terminal => "jpeg",
        bg         => 'white',
        pm3d       => 'map',
        palette    => 'defined (0 "white", 3 "yellow", 5  "red")',
        output     => "myImage.jpeg",
        title      => "wafer distribution",
        xlabel     => 'x',
        ylabel     => 'y',
        xrange     => [-1, 5],
        yrange     => [-1, 5],
    );
    my $dataSet = Chart::Gnuplot::DataSet->new( 
        using => '1:2:3 with image',
        points => \@data 
    );
    $chart->plot2d($dataSet);
```